# Modify m3u8 files using hls.js

Tags: javascript, http-live-streaming, hls.js

I'm using video-dev/hls.js lib to create my hls player.

I would like to modify the m3u8 index files BEFORE playing the video.

For example, I'd like to put a program-date header in it:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:6
#EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY
>>>> #EXT-X-PROGRAM-DATE-TIME ...<<<<
#EXTINF:5.504,
0.ts
```

I've been looking through their documentation but had no success using the loaders.

Comment: Worst case scenario, you can always fetch the manifest yourself, modify, dump to a blob, and use that blob URL when you initialize HLS.js.

Comment: you can add delegate to the load and change it before its going into the engine - https://github.com/video-dev/hls.js/blob/master/docs/API.md#ploader